# How to use bash to open multiple screen and let them run independently

Tags: linux, bash, expect, gnu-screen

Screen only supports ctrl+a+d for temporary departure, I try to use expect's send "/ 01d" but there is no response, there is no response to executing the expect script alone in screen, is there a better way to complete execution in screen and create the next screen?

I had a lot of scripts to monitor and might need to monitor in real time, so I chose screen to manage them, and now I want to write a script that quickly traverses and runs all the scripts in the directory.

I execute changed.sh directly in screen

change.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
send "\01d"
```

According to other people's answers, screen should have generated the Detached event.

full scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#cd /home/centos/Recorder/config
#ls|grep .txt|sed 's/.txt//g'
for ((NUM=$(ls /home/centos/Recorder/config|grep -c .txt); NUM>0; --NUM)) 
do
NAME=$(ls /home/centos/Recorder/config|grep .txt|sed 's/.txt//g'|sed -n "$NUM"p)
sleep 3
screen -S $NAME /home/centos/Recorder/index.sh $NAME
sleep 3
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF 
send "\01"
send "d" 
expect eof
EOF
done
```

Comment: Please paste your full ([mcve]) script.

Comment: In screen, after change.sh was executed, it was supposed to be detached,problem is here

Answer (score 0):

use this can solve without ex

```
screen -dmS $NAME
```